# What's the sufficient or necessary conditions for a manifold to have Lie group structure?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology

For example, given a Lie group, its fundamental group must be Abelian. So $\Sigma_g$ ($g>1$)  can't have Lie group structure. We also know for  $S^n$ only $n=0,1,3$ can have Lie group  structures.

In general, what's the sufficient **or** necessary conditions for a manifold to have Lie group structure?

Comment: I can think of a couple more *necessary* conditions: the second homotopy group must be trivial, and the third torsion-free, according to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8957/homotopy-groups-of-lie-groups?rq=1 . Also, the (co)homology with field coefficients must carry a Hopf algebra structure.

Comment: Of course a Lie group is parallelisable.

Comment: A  related  post could be  the  following  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5262/lie-groups-and-manifolds/5492#5492

Comment: I'll understand the question in the smooth setting. 1) A manifold has a Lie group structure iff all its components are diffeomorphic and if some of its component admits a Lie group structure. This reduces to the connected case. 2) A connected manifold has a Lie group structure iff it's diffeomorphic to $K\times\mathbf{R}^n$ for some $n$ and some compact Lie group $K$. This reduces to the connected compact case, for which there is a full classification.

Comment: Another remark about $\pi_3$: if a connected manifold carries a Lie group structure and has trivial $\pi_3$ then it's a torus.

Answer (score 11):

Compact Lie groups are finite loop spaces, but Andersen, Bauer, Grodal, Pedersen (Invent. Math., 2004) give an example of a finite loop space that is not (even rationally) homotopy equivalent to any compact Lie group.